# Laptop sound issue. Speakers are working, but the headphone doesn't

Tags: sound, headphones

I have a strange issue with Xubuntu after a reinstall. Laptop speakers are working, but the earphone does not (sic!). Seems it is more common to have this problem the other way around.

Please help

Comment: Why have you added "(sic!)"?

Comment: Some threads suggest that after going to standby, it works. if not , launch alsamixer and search muted faders (look https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/Alsamixer   )  . There was also cases where you had to do a real shutdown from windows  (not a  reboot)

Comment: Added "sic" because I saw a lot of topics for things going the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a hardware issue. It was working before in both Windows and Linux. Now it doesn't work with Linux either.